# org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException: Odd number of characters

Tags: java, encriptación

Tengo el siguiente error en compilación de pruebas y me gustaría me ayudaran a solucionarlo:

```
String nonce2 = "11111";
String api_key = "271e6189-c251-4067-ab55";
String api_secret = "c9f98b81-e825-4588-b095";

String algorithm = "HmacSHA256";

byte[] keyBytes = Hex.decodeHex((api_key+nonce2).toCharArray());
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, algorithm);

Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
mac.init(secretKeySpec);
byte[] macBytes = mac.doFinal(api_secret.getBytes());

String hexBytes = new String(Hex.encodeHex(macBytes));
System.out.println(hexBytes);
```

Y me manda el error del título

```
org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException: Odd number of characters.
```

¿Qué debo hacer para mejorarlo?

Este es mi StackTrace

> org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException: Odd number of characters. at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.decodeHex(Hex.java:59) at com.alodiga.transferto.integration.connection.RequestManager.testNauta(RequestMa‌​nager.java:297) at transfertotopupintegration.Main.main(Main.java:29)

Comment: No parece ser un error de compilación sino de tiempo de ejecución. Por favor publica el stacktrace y la línea donde aparece el error.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y publica allí el stacktrace. No lo coloques en un comentario.

Comment: Si te fijas en la documentación del métod `decodeHex` notarás que indica lo siguiente: "Se lanza una excepción si la matriz de caracteres pasada tiene un número impar de elementos" y efectivamente eso es lo que significa el mensaje en el stackTrace "Se lanza (una DecoderException) si un número impar o ilegal de caracteres se suministra"; es decir tu `api_key+nonce2`

Answer (score 2):

Te puedo sugerir los siguientes mejoras:

**1) La clave para generar un HMac no es una contraseña**

La clave para un HMac debería ser criptográficamente aleatorio. Considera generarlo usando `SecureRandom#nextBytes(byte[] bytes);`.

**2) Para generar suficiente entropía, se recomienda un tamaño >= tamaño del bloque.**

Si tu eliminas los characteres invalidos del `api_key` para convertir la representación en hex > bytes te quedan 10 bytes = 80 bits. Tu HMac tiene un tamaño de bloque de 256 bits, así para no bajar la fuerza de la encriptación necesitarías un nonce de mínimo 176 bits.

**En resumen:**

- Genera la clave usando por ejemplo (simplificado) `byte[] keyBytes = new byte[32]; SecureRandom.getInstance().nextBytes(keyBytes);`.
- Guarda la clave en un lugar asegurado aparte del almacenamiento del *Hash* que quieres generar (no en la misma BBDD), si lo transfieres sobre una conexión no segura, usa encriptación asincrónica (por ejemplo RSA).

La razón para la excepción ya tienes en el comentario de [@RosendoRopher](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/191/rosendo-ropher)